# app.js:94 Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'after') Expression: "countries"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

I got the error attached below and the select drop-down isn't showing. Also provided is the file causing the error. [file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/691lh.png)

[uncaught error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID8aB.png)

The expected results is that when user clicks select country, a select dropdown appears and the user can select their country

Comment: Do not post the code as an image.

Comment: Check the value of country.code, it might be undefined.